# Does a unique column constraint affect the performance of INSERT operations in SQL Server

Tags: sql, sql-server, entity-framework

I am wondering if having a UNIQUE column constraint will slow down the performance of insert operations on a table.

Comment: As opposed to what? It will be implemented with an index. So are you comparing it with no index on the column or an existing non unique one?

Comment: It requires checking an index.  So yes this takes more time than just inserting the row.

Comment: @MartinSmith Actually the unique constraint is on two columns. And yes, a non-clustered index will be created on the two columns. I am a bit worried because the database will experience a significant amount of inserts everyday (about 40,000 inserts)

Comment: Hi @GH_eng, was your question addressed?. If so, can you please mark it as answered?

Answer (score 3):

I would say, yes.
The difference between inserting into HEAP with and without such constraint will be visible since general rule applies: more indexes - slower inserts. Also unique index has to be checked if a row can be inserted or such value (or combination) already exists, so double work.

The slowdown will be more visible on bulk inserts of large amounts of rows. And vice versa on single spotted inserts the impact going to be smaller.

The other thing that unique constraints and indexes help query optimizer to build better SELECT plans...

Answer (score 3):

Yes, indexes will slow it down marginally (perhaps not even noticeably).

**HOWEVER**, do not forego proper database design to because you want it to be fast as possible. Indexes will slow down an insert a tiny amount; if this amount is unacceptable, your design is almost certainly wrong in the first place and you are attacking the issue from the wrong angle.

When in doubt, test. If you need to be able to insert 100,000 rows a minute. Test that scenario.

Answer (score 2):

Typically no. SQL Server creates an index and SQL Server can quickly determine if the value already exist. Maybe in a an enormous table (billions of rows) but I have never seen it. Unique constraints are very a very useful and convenient way to guarantee data consistancy.

Comment: Hello. Are you saying once a unique column constraint is defined, sql server automatically creates an index under the covers ??